# Classic Azure Mobile services scheduler in new Azure Portal

Tags: node.js, azure, push-notification, azure-webjobs

I am using classic Azure portal and it does have Mobile services.I was able to create mobile service and run javascript(Node backend) backend code for sending push notifications connecting notification hubs.But in the new portal I am trying to do the same that is creating a new mobile service and run Javascript code (Node backend) for push notifications.As expected I am unable to find mobile services as old mobile service is now Mobile App.I am exploring Mobile App under App services but unable to find a option to create new scheduler that runs a Node script.I am only able to create a web job.Is it not possible to create a scheduler that runs Node script in new Azure?

Comment: you can create a function app that runs node code and schedule it as a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can build up your own Node.js application with several functionalities you need, and expose them as HTTP REST APIs. Then you can use new Scheduler jobs on new Azure protal (https://ms.portal.azure.com) to call your own APIs in a schedule.

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-intro/ for more info.